# How to get table fully copied from html to MS Word?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to get the `table` in `html` fully copied from browser (works in Chrome) to Word document. What happens is that last row's border doesn't get passed in Word.

Take the code:

HTML:

```
<table id="t6">
<tr><th></th><th>raw_alpha</th><th>std.alpha</th><th>G6(smc)</th><th>average_r</th></tr>
<tr><td>gse1</td><td>0.88</td><td>0.88</td><td>0.88</td><td>0.45</td></tr>
<tr><td>gse10</td><td>0.88</td><td>0.88</td><td>0.88</td><td>0.45</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table, th, tr, td {
        background-color:white;
        border-spacing: 0;
        padding: 2px 6px;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        text-align: right;
    }

th {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color: #000;
    border-style: solid none solid none;
}

tr:last-child {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-style: none none solid none;
}
```

Is there any way to make the last row's border be included? Also is there a possibility for this to work in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borders applied to `tr` elements are apparently not recognized, so you need to apply them to `td` instead.
In your CSS, change `tr:last-child` to `tr:last-child td` and it should work.

Comment: Awesome, that does it.